# Impala query over odbc canceled (don't know the reason)

Tags: impala, cloudera-cdh

From time to time queries gets canceled without a reason. I don't know if the query gets canceled by the coordinator or by the app who initiated the queries.

Anyone had this problem before or knows how to solve it?

```
coordinator.cc started execution on 9 backends for query_id=xxx
client-request-state.cc:545] xxx] Cancelled right after starting the coordinator query id=xxx
coordinator.cc:488] xxx] ExecState: query id=xxx execution cancelled
coordinator-backend-state.cc:445] xxx] Sending CancelQueryFInstances rpc for query_id=xxx
coordinator-backend-state.cc:445] xxx] Sending CancelQueryFInstances rpc for query_id=xxx
control-service.cc:169] CancelQueryFInstances(): query_id=xxx
query-exec-mgr.cc:97] QueryState: query_id=xxx refcnt=5
query-state.cc:667] Cancel: query_id=xxx
krpc-data-stream-mgr.cc:326] cancelling all streams for fragment_instance_id=xxx
krpc-data-stream-mgr.cc:326] cancelling all streams for fragment_instance_id=xxx
```

Comment: I am using the pypyodbc lib in python and facing the same issue and for me this specifically happening when executing insert query though at the same time I am able to execute it from impala-shell.